# CosmosDB and Python3: how to query?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using CosmosDB (Azure documentDB) in my project, written in Python 3.

I have been looking for a while now, but I cannot find out how to query my table. I have seen some example code, but I do not see an example of how to query... all I can do is get all documents (not ideal when my DB is > 80GB).

The GitHub repo shows a very tiny set of operations for database and collections: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-python/blob/master/samples/CollectionManagement/Program.py

And the [following SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44258236/596841) post shows how to read all documents... but not how to perform querying such as "WHERE  = X;"

I'd really appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction, and possibly supply an example showing how to run queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my understanding, I think you want to know how to perform a SQL-like query using Python to retrieve documents on Azure CosmosDB of DocumentDB API, please refer to the code below from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-documentdb-python#review-the-code).

> A query is performed using SQL
>
> ```
> # Query them in SQL
> query = { 'query': 'SELECT * FROM server s' }    
>
> options = {} 
> options['enableCrossPartitionQuery'] = True
> options['maxItemCount'] = 2
>
> result_iterable = client.QueryDocuments(collection['_self'], query, options)
> results = list(result_iterable);
>
> print(results)
> ```

The above code is using the method [`QueryDocuments`](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-python/api/pydocumentdb.document_client.html#pydocumentdb.document_client.DocumentClient.QueryDocuments).

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

---

Update: Combine with my sample code for the other SO thread you linked, as below.

```
from pydocumentdb import document_client

uri = 'https://ronyazrak.documents.azure.com:443/'
key = '<your-primary-key>'

client = document_client.DocumentClient(uri, {'masterKey': key})

db_id = 'test1'
db_query = "select * from r where r.id = '{0}'".format(db_id)
db = list(client.QueryDatabases(db_query))[0]
db_link = db['_self']

coll_id = 'test1'
coll_query = "select * from r where r.id = '{0}'".format(coll_id)
coll = list(client.QueryCollections(db_link, coll_query))[0]
coll_link = coll['_self']

query = { 'query': 'SELECT * FROM server s' }    
docs = client.QueryDocuments(coll_link, query)
print list(docs)
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please define `collection` for completeness? I have an existing collection, I am not creating one.

Comment: @pookie Please see my update, it combined with my sample code for the other SO thread you linked. Is it you want?

Comment: Thanks, this worked with some modifications: need to include the `options` in the `QueryDocuments` call, changed `print` to Python3, `list` does not work (causes program to hang). I instead used:

    constraint = 'something'
    query = "SELECT * FROM r WHERE r.
    <column_name>='{0}'".format(constraint)   
    docs = client.QueryDocuments(coll_link, query, options)
    for doc in docs:
        print(doc)

I could not edit your answer as it kept telling me that there was code not formatted correctly (it was a lie!)

Comment: I am following this same procedure however I cannot get my query to work, I use an `order by` clause like so;
`SELECT * FROM c ORDER BY c._ts desc`

Comment: Do not put raw params into the query. If it comes from user input it's an easy SQLi. Use parameters instead: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/samples/database_management.py#L43

Answer (score 1):

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM c'
docs = list(client.QueryItems(coll_link,query))
```

QueryDocuments has been replaced with QueryItems.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem recently. You can fetch blocks (not entire query set) by calling fetch_next_block().

```
query = "select * from c"
options = {'maxItemCount': 1000, 'continuation': True}
q = db_source._client.QueryDocuments(collection_link, query, options)
block1 = q.fetch_next_block()
block2 = q.fetch_next_block()
```

Comment: Cool! You might want to put that into a generator, though!