# How to read Azure CosmosDb Collection in Databricks and write to a Spark DataFrame

Tags: python, azure, cosmos

I am querying a CosmosDb collection, and, could able to print the results.  When I try to store the results to a Spark DataFrame, it fails.

Referred this site as an example:

[How to read data from Azure's CosmosDB in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249604/how-to-read-data-from-azures-cosmosdb-in-python)

Followed the exact steps from above link. Additionally, trying the below

```
 df = spark.createDataFrame(dataset)
```

This throws this error:

> ### ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined after inferring
>
> ValueError
>   Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>        25 print (dataset)
>        26
>   ---> 27 df = spark.createDataFrame(dataset)
>        28 df.show()
>        29
>
> /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
>       808                 rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
>       809             else:
>   --> 810                 rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
>       811             jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
>       812             jdf = self._jsparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), schema.json())
>
> /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in _createFromLocal(self, data, schema)
>       440         write temp files.
>       441         """
>   --> 442         data, schema = self._wrap_data_schema(data, schema)
>       443         return self._sc.parallelize(data), schema

But, wanting this to save as a Spark DataFrame

any help would be much appreciated.  thanks!!!>

Comment: did you try to follow the official example? https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/cosmosdb-connector.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to infer the field type, PySpark looks at the non-none records in each field. If a field only has None records, PySpark can not infer the type and will raise that error.

Manually defining a schema will resolve the issue

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
>>> schema = StructType([StructField("foo", StringType(), True)])
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([[None]], schema=schema)
>>> df.show()
+----+
|foo |
+----+
|null|
+----+
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I see you were following my previous answer using an old Python SDK for DocumentDB to query CosmosDB documents to create a PySpark DataFrame object. But you can not directly pass the result `docs` from `client.ReadDocuments` method as the parameter `data` to the function [`SparkSession.createDataFrame(data, schema=None, samplingRatio=None, verifySchema=True)`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame), because the data types are different, as below.

The function `createDataFrame` requires a parameter `data` which must be a `RDD` or `list` or `pandas.DataFrame`

[image]

However, I downloaded the source codes of [`pydocumentdb-2.3.3.tar.gz`](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/53/310ef5bd836e54f8a8c3d4da8c9a8c9b21c6bb362665e018eb27c41a1518/pydocumentdb-2.3.3.tar.gz) from https://pypi.org/project/pydocumentdb/#files and reviewed the code files `document_client.py` & `query_iterable.py`.

```
# from document_client.py
def ReadDocuments(self, collection_link, feed_options=None):
    """Reads all documents in a collection.

    :param str collection_link:
        The link to the document collection.
    :param dict feed_options:

    :return:
        Query Iterable of Documents.
    :rtype:
        query_iterable.QueryIterable

    """
    if feed_options is None:
        feed_options = {}

    return self.QueryDocuments(collection_link, None, feed_options)

# query_iterable.py
class QueryIterable(object):
    """Represents an iterable object of the query results.
    QueryIterable is a wrapper for query execution context.
    """
```

So to fix your issue, you have to create a `pandas.DataFrame` object first via iterate the result `Query Iterable of Documents` from `ReadDocuments` method, then to create a PySpark DataFrame object via `spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)`.